# Добавление нового типа файла в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Имеется необходимость редактировать в Visual Studio 2015 свои типы файлов (XML типа XAML и специфический JavaScript, не для HTML). Расширения файлов, естественно, отличаются от стандартных.

Хотелось бы упростить редактирование:

1. Написанием своего валидатора и IntelliSense для XML (отступы атрибутов, подсказка атрибутов, подсветка кода)
2. Доработкой IntelliSense для JavaScript, а именно:

   - Go To Definition (F12). Имеющийся далеко не всегда находит.
   - подсказка своих свойств, которых нет в стандартном JavaScript.

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли это и в какую сторону копать?

Есть ли исходники стандартных IntelliSense для XAML и JavaScript для их доработки?

[image: File Extension]